# getting top X items in each folder with a CAML Query

Tags: javascript, web-services, caml-query, paging

i'm trying to do a visual representation of a document library using javascript and webservices.

basically i want to present the folders in the library, with a preview of the first few files in each folder.

so far, best solution i could find for this was to load the folder structure and then do a query for each of the folders asynchronously. 
I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a single query?

If there is any other solution (client or server side) that can get this result I'll be thankful as well.

Thank you for your time!